# uitextview refreshing when using image picker or take a new photo iphone device?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller

Hello good morning everyone, i am having a weird issue when using imagePickerController. Actually i have a view with 2 uitextviews. the user input some text and then take a option to add a photo with the text in the uitextviews to be sent. i select attach photo from there either i take a new photo using camera or i select from library , once selected the imagePickerController disappears BUT here i have 2 situation with 3 actual devices i tested :

1. Iphone 3G IOS 4.2.1 > ok the text i input earlier is still on the view.
2. IPhone 3GS IOS 4.3 > the text dissappears
3. iPhone 3GS another device IOS 4.3 > the text remains.

Is this a memory issue or a bug somewhere?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case If you get a proper solution for this then let me know because I faced the same problem. For the time being I save all the content in a dictionary prior to presenting the Picker. Once the Picker is dismissed I fill The details back in viewWillAppear: method. I am still looking for a standard approach to resolve this issues.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (!registrationDataDict) 
    {
        registrationDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    else {
        if (![registrationDataDict valueForKeyIsNull:@"USER_NAME"]) 
        {
            [UserNameTexeFied setText:[registrationDataDict valueForKey:@"USER_NAME"]];
        }
        if (![registrationDataDict valueForKeyIsNull:@"FIRST_NAME"]) 
        {
            [FNameTextFied setText:[registrationDataDict valueForKey:@"FIRST_NAME"]];
        }
        if (![registrationDataDict valueForKeyIsNull:@"LAST_NAME"]) 
        {
            [LNameTextFied setText:[registrationDataDict valueForKey:@"LAST_NAME"]];
        }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Hello thanks you for your kind response :) well i am using a setter and getter variables, it works for the first UItextfield but for the UITextView it doesnot .. 

Here is my Code :

onViewwillAppear{
  
                // UiTextField
  txta.text=temp_a;
                // UI TExtView
                //if i re assign the value i.e uncomment b_temp it works great
  //b_temp=@"TESTING";
                // else if getting the last value it doesnot 
  [txtb setText:b_temp];
}

onViewwillDispear{
temp_a=txta.text;
b_temp=txtb.text;
}

Again Many thanks :)

Comment: i tried this on view will disappear :


b_temp=[self.txtb text]; but getting bad access ...

Comment: I got to work, in fact i was not retaining the value of the Nsstring :) Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a bug somewhere in your code. The reason is, there are some differences in ios 4.3 and 4.2. I can trace the bug if you post your code.
Cheers!

Comment: Hi there thanks for your kind consideration, i tried to manually figured out but having a problem to assign the value on viewwillappear. Many many thanks again :) :)